# Obtener primer y último día del mes, primer día del mes anterior y último día del mes siguiente

Tags: java, java-swing, java-8

Quisiera obtener el primer y último día del mes, el primer día del mes anterior y el último día del mes siguiente teniendo en cuenta que escojo el mes en un combobox y el año. Quisiera mostrar eso en un jchooser. No sé si es posible.

```
    Date fechaf = fechaFinal.getDate();
    Date fechai = fechaInicio.getDate();
    Date mesSig = mesSiguiente.getDate();
    Date mesAnt = mesAnterior.getDate();

    int a = Integer.valueOf((String) jcAnio.getSelectedItem());
    int m = Integer.valueOf((String) jcMes.getSelectedItem());
```

Comment: con jchooser te refieres a https://www.softsmithy.org/softsmithy-lib/lib/2.0/docs/site/apidocs/index.html?org/softsmithy/lib/swing/action/package-summary.html ?

Answer (score 3):

Utilizando [Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) como en el código que muestro a continuación:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");  
//Fecha actual
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
System.out.println("Fecha Actual:" + sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));

//A la fecha actual le pongo el día 1
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1);
System.out.println("Primer día del mes actual:" + sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));

//Se le agrega 1 mes 
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1);
System.out.println("Fecha del del siguiente mes:" + sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
System.out.println("1-Último día del mes siguiente " + calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

//Se le quita 1 mes
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)-2);//le quito 2 meses porque ya le había sumado 1 mes
System.out.println("Fecha del primer día del mes anterior: " + sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
System.out.println("2.- Primer día del mes anterior" + calendar.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

A la fecha actual le pongo el día `1`, esto es porque si llega el día `31/01/2019`, y le sumo `1` mes se va hasta Marzo y con esto si le sumo 1 mes se queda en **`01/02/2019`**, y con la función **`getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)`**, obtengo el máximo día del mes, después a esa misma instancia le resto `2` meses porque ya le había sumado `1` y obtengo la fecha **`01/12/2018`**, de hecho ya no tendría que utilizar la función **`getActualMinimum`**, pero la puse para fines ilustrativos.

**Este es el resultado:**

```
Fecha Actual:22/01/2019

Primer día del mes actual:01/01/2019

Fecha del siguiente mes:01/02/2019

1-Último día del mes siguiente 28

Fecha del primer día del mes anterior: 01/12/2018

2.- Primer día del mes anterior1
```

Answer (score 1):

Antes que nada, si te fijas en: [Clase Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) te dice que ya esta obsoleta, capaz te conviene usar la clase **Calendar**. Aclardo esto ahora si vamos al problema.
Si mal no entendi, elegis un mes, por ejemplo Febrero, y deberia mostrarte 1 de Enero y 
31 de Marzo? Entonces obtenes el mes (que es de tipo **int**) luego le restas y sumas uno respectivamente. Es lo mas que te puedo ayudar ya que no tengo mucho idea de la clase Date. Saludos!